# Undefined index: user_name

Tags: php

When I try to use the user_name from $_SESSION I get the error

> 'Undefined index: user_name'

**CODE:**

```
  $_SESSION['signed_in'] = true;

  while ($row = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $_SESSION['user_id']    = $row['user_id'];
    $_SESSION['user_name']  = $row['user_first_name'];
  }

  echo 'Welcome, ' . $_SESSION['user_name'] . '. <a href="index.php">Proceed to the overview page to see your tasks</a>.';
```

Comment: session_start() on the top of file, and isset($_SESSION) or var_dump do.

Comment: Have you added `session_start();` at the beginning ?

Comment: yeah I added session_start() and still not working

Comment: Are you getting any data back from your query? Echo inside your while loop to see.

Comment: i am getting data and when i use var_dump on _$SESSION i get 
array (size=1)
  'signed_in' => boolean true

Comment: If you var_dump( $row ); inside the loop, what do you get?

Comment: And there's your problem. When you say nothing I presume you mean absolutely nothing. Meaning it never runs (var_dump never outputs absolutely nothing), because your query returns no data.  Therefore you never actually set the values of user_id and user_name in $_SESSION.

Comment: I'd like to contest that this is a duplicate of the question referenced.  The question referenced describes the generic issue of accessing a variable before it is set to a value and points towards declaring the variable.  However, this is a LOGICAL error.  There is an assumption that the `fetch` will return a row, when this is not always the case.  I'd leave an answer to that effect with helpful code, but I can't as the answer has been marked as duplicate presumably by people who did not actually work out the problem and instead just saw "undefined index" and blindly marked it.

Answer (score 1):

Add session_start(); on top of your page to start the session.

Comment: i did that already but it is not working